# From C++, is there a way I can get file version information of a C# exe?

Tags: c++

I am in VS2013 C++ and I use `GetFileVersionInfoSize` and `GetFileVersionInfo` to get the file version of exe's that were built with C++. I now want the ability to get the file version from exe's that were built with C#.

Comment: ...does `GetFileVersionInfo` not work on C# executables? That would surprise me a bit.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. C# executables can and do have version info that's retrievable with `GetFileVersionInfo`.

Comment: Most probably he's referring to the File Version of .NET assembly (this could not be retrieve with any Win32 API), it's encoded inside the MS IL of the assembly.